# Does Calculate Value run only once in Batch mode?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, batch

I wrote a model with a model-only tool (Calculate Value) as the first step. While running the model in single time, it works fine. But while run in batch mode, it yields silly results. I checked the log (messages) of the batch processing and found that the Calculate Value ran only once while the rest of the model run multiple times. I confirmed Calculate Value running only once is the cause of the silly results. Does this mean the model-only tool (Calculate Value) can only run once in batch mode? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Some further information on how you incorporated the calculation in your model, as well as what you are calculating could be helpful.

Comment: It may be worth testing the equivalent workflow in ArcGIS Pro's ModelBuilder.